# Loading only the last 10 lines from csv file in dygraphs

Tags: javascript, csv, dygraphs

Using the example code from the [tutorial](http://dygraphs.com/tutorial.html):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="dygraph-combined.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="graphdiv2"
  style="width:500px; height:300px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  g2 = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
    "temperatures.csv", // path to CSV file
    {}          // options
  );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd like to load only the last 10 lines from [temperatures.csv](http://dygraphs.com/temperatures.csv) instead of the whole file. Can I pass an instruction to the dygraphs' csv parser to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such option to set limit or/and offset according to source code https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/master/dygraph.js#L2942

But you can override function `Dygraph.prototype.parseCSV_` in your code to achieve this.

For example like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgbmg/):

```
// Save old function
var parseCSV_ = Dygraph.prototype.parseCSV_;

Dygraph.prototype.parseCSV_ = function(data) {
    // Get all data
    var ret = parseCSV_(data);

    // Return only last 10 items
    return ret.slice(ret.length - 10);
};

g2 = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
    "temperatures.csv", // path to CSV file
    {}          // options
);
```

P.S. I'd recommend you to use new `CSV` file with only last 10 items to speed up loading, so generate it on back end if it is possible.

Comment: My use case is this: I have a long file with data for a couple of years. This file is updated every 10 minutes with new data. I want to create graphs that show data for the last day, week, month. Is it still more efficient to create separate csv files every time? This is running on a RaspberryPi computer which has a USB drive for storage so I'd also like to minimize writes.

Comment: If you want to show day, week and month on 1 page I'd used 1 file for this. So on backend I'd create file with only last month data and other (all) data in separate file. For example `temperatures-month.csv` and `temperatures.csv`. Then load file with month data and limit it for a day or week with my approach. However this approach allows you only use limitation once. You can rewrite it to accept options to set number of lines.